# jqGrid - No such method: setFrozenColumns

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid 4.1.2, a sample of the code used to create the grid is shown below. Everything works fine until I try to set frozen columns at which point a runtime error is thrown - ' jqGrid - No such method: setFrozenColumns ' - can anyone see why this is happening ?

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: '@Url.Action("LoadGrid")',
    editurl: '@Url.Action("UpdateGrid")',
    datatype: 'json',
    shrinkToFit: false,
    autowidth: true,
    mtype: 'POST',
    ..... columns ....
    rowNum: 100,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
    sortname: 'Id',
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Instances',
    height: 225
});
$("#grid").navGrid("#pager", { edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: false });
$("#grid").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
```

Comment: Do you mean jqGrid 4.1.2 or jqGrid 4.2.1? It's sure not jqGrid 1.4.2. Which version of jqGrid you use? Probably it is not yet support frozen columns?

Comment: apologies - version is 4.1.2. I can see the function in jquery.jqgrid.min.js and it is called out in the documentation so the method should be supported.

Comment: Sorry, but `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` can't have `setFrozenColumns` inside. You should verify that one more time. You can examine [source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.custom.js) of  jqGrid and see no `setFrozenColumns`. You can first find the function if jqGrid 4.3.0 (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.0/js/grid.custom.js#L621)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that frozen columns are supported started with 4.3.0 version of jqGrid. To be able to use the feature you have to update jqGrid which you use.